Clarification on FIDE Rating Calculation for End-of-Month Tournaments
I 'm seeking clarification on FIDE rating calculations for tournaments held at the end of a month, particularly for blitz events.
Here's a specific scenario:
A FIDE-rated blitz tournament takes place on September 30th.
Player A's September rating: 1400
Player A's October rating: 1600 (hypothetical significant increase)
If calculated using September rating: Player A gains +50 points
If calculated using October rating: Player A loses -75 points
The FIDE Title Regulations clearly state that for title norms, "The Rating List in effect at the start of the tournament shall be used." However, I'm uncertain if this applies to regular rating calculations for non-title events.
Questions:

Which rating (September or October) would FIDE use to calculate the rating change for this tournament?

Is there a specific regulation in the FIDE Rating Rules addressing this scenario for regular tournaments?

How does FIDE handle rating calculations when there's a significant rating change between the tournament date and the processing date?


I'd greatly appreciate any insights or references to official FIDE documents that clarify this situation.

If a player gains 200 points - where do you think these come from? There must be other results too, no? So, at latest by the end of October the player would end up with the same rating.

@bakunin No, the way the ratings are calculated, it likely won't be the same. If you draw against a 1500 player, your rating will go down if 1600 is used for the calculation, but it will go up if 1400 is used.

Answers to your questions:
1 - FIDE considers the 30th and 31st too late to have time to update the rating for this month, so they defer it to the next rating cycle, which would be November the first. This means that FIDE would use the October Ratings to calculate the new rating.
According to regulation 7.1.3:
7.1.3      The closing date for tournaments for a list is 3
days before the date of the list; tournaments ending before
or on that day may be rated on the list. Official FIDE events
may be rated on the list even if they end on the last day
before the list date.
2 and 3 - There is no specific regulation, but I may have overlooked something. Here is the list of rating regulations according to FIDE: https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/B022024
